# How to Use QuestionObject with AssessmentResultObject?

Tags: user-interface

The documentation is very unclear as to how these should be combined to generate a result for further processing.

For example, we have:

```
    QuestionObject["How many career home runs did Hank Aaron hit?", 
 x = AssessmentFunction[{714 -> False, 755 -> True, 868 -> False}]]
```

which produces the following:

[image]

But how to get the result (True or False in this case)?

x is the AssessmentFunction:

```
AssessmentFunction[{714 -> False, 755 -> True, 868 -> False}]
```

The documentation appears to imply that an AssessmentResultObject is automatically created and should be accessible using:

`x["property"]`, where "property is, for instance, "AnswerCorrect".

But this doesn't work, nor do any of the other possibilities, giving an error:

```
AssessmentFunction::invans: The provided answer is not supported by the comparison method of the assessment function.
```

So how should QuestionObject be used to generate a result for further processing?

Comment: If you're not somehow pulling this from the `Notebook` expression, you'd programmatically get it like: ```x[755]["AnswerCorrect"]```. The underlying box structure is a `DynamicModule` that you can destructure if you know how